# Google map API set the map with specific location and search on it

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

is it  possible to locate not all map on my web page? I want that it show only specific location for example city.

How can I search on specific location, not whole map

Answer (score -1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/9d4jy4ye/

```
  <div id="map" style="width: 400px; height: 300px;"></div>    

 // This is the minimum zoom level that we'll allow
     var minZoomLevel = 5;

     var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
         zoom: minZoomLevel,
         center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.50, -90.50),
         mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
     });

     // Bounds for North America
     var strictBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
     new google.maps.LatLng(28.70, -127.50),
     new google.maps.LatLng(48.85, -55.90));

     // Listen for the dragend event
     google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend', function () {
         if (strictBounds.contains(map.getCenter())) return;

         // We're out of bounds - Move the map back within the bounds

         var c = map.getCenter(),
             x = c.lng(),
             y = c.lat(),
             maxX = strictBounds.getNorthEast().lng(),
             maxY = strictBounds.getNorthEast().lat(),
             minX = strictBounds.getSouthWest().lng(),
             minY = strictBounds.getSouthWest().lat();

         if (x < minX) x = minX;
         if (x > maxX) x = maxX;
         if (y < minY) y = minY;
         if (y > maxY) y = maxY;

         map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(y, x));
     });

     // Limit the zoom level
     google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function () {
         if (map.getZoom() < minZoomLevel) map.setZoom(minZoomLevel);
     });
```

Comment: We're here to educate. Please explain why your answer helps solve the OPs problem so they can learn for future reference.